# simple issue of getting values to print for each iteration in for loop?

Tags: python, loops

My code is working just as I want it to but for one small issue: the 'print' line is only showing values for Bn for the first iteration (n = 2), but not for (n = 5 or 20).

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.integrate import quad

#unique depending on the problem
y = lambda t: 3*t   
T = 4      #period
w = 2*np.pi/T #angular frequency
print('Angular Frequency [rad]:',w)
n_list = np.array([2,5,20])

#for loop for multiple n values:
for n in n_list:

    Bn = (2/T)*quad(lambda t: y(t)*np.sin(n*w*t), -T/2, T/2)[0]  #for odd functions  
    An = (2/T)*quad(lambda t: y(t)*np.cos(n*w*t), -T/2, T/2)[0]  #for even
    A0 = (1/T)*quad(lambda t: y(t), -T/2, T/2)[0]   #vertical shift

    y = lambda t: A0+An*np.cos(n*w*t)+Bn*np.sin(n*w*t) #total equation

    t = np.linspace(-6, 6)
    plt.plot(t,y(t))
    plt.title('n = %d'%n)
    print('Coefficients [V]:', 'Bn:',Bn, 'An:', An,'A0:', A0)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I copied the code and it works for me in jupyter, printing correctly each line and plotting each chart

Answer (score 0):

The print line `print('Coefficients [V]:', 'Bn:',Bn, 'An:', An,'A0:', A0)` is executed before the `plt.show()` line gets executed, so the string is printed when `n = 2` then a window opens. The problem is that you cannot continue looping in the `for` loop while this `plt.show()` method is still running. If you try to close the opened window you'll see the message for `n = 5` gets printed.

If you want the full result of the array to be printed, you can consider storing them in a variable and printing it after the loop ends. Or you can find an alternative way to implement `plt.show()`.